# android device is not worked

Tags: android, soap, android-emulator, device

i have develope one calculation example using soap webservices.it is scuuessfully worked on my emulator.but it is not worked on my android real device.why dis is not worked on my device.

dis is my code:

```
package org.web.frontend.calculator;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.net.SocketException;

import org.ksoap2.SoapEnvelope;
import org.ksoap2.serialization.SoapObject;
import org.ksoap2.serialization.SoapSerializationEnvelope;
import org.ksoap2.transport.HttpTransportSE;
import org.ksoap2.transport.ServiceConnection;
import org.xmlpull.v1.XmlPullParserException;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.util.Log;
public class AndroidWSDLFrontEnd extends Activity {

private String METHOD_NAME ="sum";
private String NAMESPACE = "http://calculator.backend.web.org";
private String SOAP_ACTION = NAMESPACE + METHOD_NAME; // NAMESPACE + method name
private static final String URL = "http://192.168.1.168:8085/Calculation/services /Calculate?wsdl"; // you must use ipaddress here, don’t use Hostname or localhost

/** Called when the activity is first created. */
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
setContentView(R.layout.main);
TextView tv = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.txtAddition);


try
{
SoapObject request = new SoapObject(NAMESPACE, METHOD_NAME);
request.addProperty("i", 15);
request.addProperty("j", 10);

SoapSerializationEnvelope envelope = new SoapSerializationEnvelope(SoapEnvelope.VER11);
envelope.dotNet = true;
envelope.setOutputSoapObject(request);
HttpTransportSE androidHttpTransport = new HttpTransportSE(URL);
androidHttpTransport.call(SOAP_ACTION,envelope);
Object result = envelope.getResponse();
System.out.println("Result : " + result.toString());
((TextView) findViewById (R.id.txtAddition)).setText("Addition : "+result.toString());
} catch (SocketException E) {
 E.printStackTrace();
((TextView) findViewById (R.id.txtAddition)).setText("ERROR: "   +    E.getClass().getName() + ":" + E.getMessage());
  }
 catch (IOException e) {
// TODO Auto-generated catch block
e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (XmlPullParserException e) {
// TODO Auto-generated catch block
e.printStackTrace();
  }
   }
    }
```

please help me.

Comment: explain "why dis not worked", mention the error

Comment: when i run my application that time displayed below error on my real device.java.net.SocketException. The operation is timed out error is displayed on my device.

Comment: Socket Exception are usually related to TCP errors, connect your device with PC and paste Logcat, for better understanding of your problem.

Comment: no messages is diaplayed on my logout window.

Comment: only displayed dis error on my device:error on my real device.java.net.SocketException. The operation is timed out error is displayed on my device.

Comment: have you tried this url "http://192.168.1.168:8085/Calculation/services/Calculate?wsdl" on your device browser?

Comment: displayed web page is not available

Comment: now what can i do...my ip address is 192.168.1.168 and port number is 8085 only.dis link is worked on my system browser.but not worked on my device browser.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you are not on the same network as `http://192.168.1.168:8085/Calculation/services/Calculate?wsdl%22`. Are you on the mobile network? If so, connect to the wi-fi and try. Also, if need be, you might have to configure a proxy or VPN for your network to allow access.

Answer (score 0):

check your mobile ip address and replace it with  your current given ipadrees

```
private static final String URL = "http://192.168.1.168:8085/Calculation/services /Calculate?wsdl";
```

pls also check your network connectivity wich used